# Speedup PDF/A created with ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdfa

I scan my documents with scanimage (300dpi color A4) and convert the pdf in a pdf/a compliant version with ghostscript.

`scanimage -l 0 -t 0 -x 210 -y 297 --mode color --resolution 300 | convert - -page A4 raw.pdf`

`gs -dQUIET -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOOUTERSAVE -dUseCIEColor -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=2 -sOutputFile=pdfa.pdf raw.pdf`

If I open this pdf in my favorite pdfreader (evince or qpdfview) it is very slow. Another pdf I download from the internet which is pdf/a conform too are not so slow.
If I don't use "-dUseCIEColor", my pdf loads very fast in evince but I think this is not pdf/a-conform anymore (see [here](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.04/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA)).

Maybe I miss some importend ghostscript parameter to speedup my pdf/a-pdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use UseCIEColor is the basic message. This is especially true for image data, as each image sample needs to be converted into a CIEBased colour space which is then further converted into an ICCBased space and embedded in the PDF file. Finally (on viewing) the ICCBased space is converted back to a device space (RGB). All of these are computationally intensive operations.

Unfortunately in the released versions of Ghostscript not setting UseCIEColor can lead to some colour conversions not being possible. However if your original PDF files only contain image data the very strong likelihood is that these will not occur. If you set -dColorConversionStrategy=CMYK then you should probably find your files are PDF/A compliant.

The next version of Ghostscript should have decent colour management in place for pdfwrite, you should then only need to select the colour space you want by setting -dColorConversionStrategy.

Comment: This advice gives me an error:  Invalid value for option -dColorConversionStrategy=CMYK

Comment: You need either -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK or -dColorConversionStrategy=/CMYK. -s introduces strings, -d introduces numbers or names.